# Adding additional values to $_GET and keeping old

Tags: html, get

Let's say I have site like `mydomain.com/test.php?pikazi=true`
and I have form

```
  <form action="test.php"  method="get">
    <input name="drzava-asc" type="image" src="images/sort-asc.gif">
    <input name="drzava-desc" type="image" src="images/sort-desc.gif" >
  </form>
```

How to keep existing `prikazi=true` while adding that new from form so it would be

```
mydomain.com/test.php?pikazi=true&drzava-asc.x=6&drzava-asc.y=1
```

Values for drzava-asc are generated by script cause it is image not submit button.

I took existing url with:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query_arr);
$url=http_build_query($query_arr);
```

and I could use it as hidden field, but not sure how. And is there any other way?

Comment: hehe.. are you croat/bosnian/serb?

Comment: jesam da :) hvala na pomoći

Comment: nema na čemu :) just please use english from now on here on STO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

You can just simply add a hidden field in your form:

```
<form action="test.php"  method="get">
  <input name="prikazi" type="hidden" value="true" />
  <input name="drzava-asc" type="image" src="images/sort-asc.gif">
  <input name="drzava-desc" type="image" src="images/sort-desc.gif" >
</form>
```

And that's about it :) Cheers!

Comment: The first solution won't work because `method="get"` will ignore any GET variables in the action.

Comment: Koristit ću onda ovo sa hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can't, not directly.

If you were using `POST`, you could just have `action=""` and it will keep all the `GET` variables there. However, you're using `GET` so that will overwrite them.

If you're using a server-side language such as PHP, you could do this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="get">
    <?php foreach($_GET as $k=>$v) echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$k."\" value=\"".htmlspecialchars($v)."\" />"; ?>
    Rest of form here...
</form>
```

Or something similar in JavaScript:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form'), l = forms.length, i,
    qs = location.search.substr(1).split("&"), m = qs.length, j, tmp, inp;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
  if( forms[i].method.toLowerCase() != "get") continue;
  for( j=0; j<m; j++) {
    inp = document.createElement('input');
    inp.type = "hidden";
    tmp = qs[j].split("=");
    inp.name = tmp.shift();
    inp.value = tmp.join("=");
    forms[i].appendChild(inp);
}
```

Comment: Wow that looks quite complicated, but thank you for your help

Comment: You say that like it's a bad thing? Just because the code looks complicated doesn't mean it is. Is there anything in particular that confuses you?

Comment: it is not bad, but I like doing things as simple as possible

Comment: Fair enough. The PHP should be simple enough for you. The JavaScript... well, you can fool yourself into thinking it's simpler with jQuery, but really this is as simple as it gets.